# SQL Select percentage from total based on location

Tags: postgresql, select, count, postgis

I want to solve the following question:

Give for each sports type the percentage of events in region 10 against the total number of events for that sports type.

I have two tables:

**events**: Lists all sports events. The column ‘sport_type’ defines the sports type of event; it has a point geometry.

**zones**: Lists all zones with their name ex. 'region 10'. They have a polygon geometry.

To list the number of events for each sports type I have:

```
select e.sport_type as Sport_Type, count(e.sport_type) as Number_of_Events
from events e
group by e.sport_type
```

To list the number of events for each sports type in region 10, I have:

```
select e.sport_type as Sport_Type, count(e.sport_type) as Number_of_Events
from events e
inner join zones z
on st_contains(z.geom, e.geom)
where z.name = 'region 10'
group by e.sport_type
```

to solve the question, i tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
select e1.sport_type as Sport_Type,  (x.Numev / count(e1.sport_type)) as Number_of_Events
from events e1, (select e2.sport_type as evtype, count(e2.sport_type) as Numev
from programs e2
inner join zones z
on st_contains(z.geom, e2.geom)
where z.name = 'region 10'
group by e2.sport_type) x
group by e1.sport_type, x.Numev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two sub-selects creates a very self-explanatory query:

```
SELECT sport_type, 100. * r10.total / sports.total AS r10_percent
FROM (
    SELECT sport_type, count(sport_type) AS total
    FROM events
    GROUP BY sport_type) sports
JOIN (
    SELECT sport_type, count(sport_type) AS total
    FROM events
    JOIN zones ON ST_Contains(zones.geom, events.geom)
    WHERE zones.name = 'region 10'
    GROUP BY events.sport_type) r10 USING (sport_type);
```

Comment: Because the result of the dividing is a float, it gives 0 for each row. Therefore i converted them first to a float value

Answer (score 0):

Not test yet, just try, since you have number of events, you can calculate the percentage easily (ex: 1 more select outside)

```
select 
    e.sport_type as Sport_Type, 
    count(*) as totalEvents,
    sum(CASE 
            WHEN z.name = 'region 10' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) as totalEventsInRegion10
from events e
    left join zones z on st_contains(z.geom, e.geom)
group by e.sport_type
```